# What tools You're using to develop Windows mobile apps on Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, windows-mobile

What tools You're using ? I don't mean the text editor, but tools, libraries, debuggers, emulators and so on...

Comment: qemu+Windows XP+Visual Studio? Sorry, you can't downvote comments ;-)

Comment: Have a look at MonoTouch (www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch) can give some idea.

Comment: astropanic, maybe you should first ask _if_ anybody is using Linux for targeting WinMobile. I very much doubt that anybody bothered to create tools for this combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely Windows mobile is such a Microsoft propriety system, that Visual Studio on Windows is the obvious (only?) choice?

Otherwise I'd guess it'll have to be Mono's equivalent of the .Net Compact Framework, using Mono Develop presumably.

Why would you want to develop for windows mobile using Linux, it seems an odd thing to do.

Comment: Maybe it's odd, but I have a WM phone, and don't want to use Windows on my Laptop.

Comment: Mono itself is quite small, so you can use actual framework, there is no need for compact framework.

Comment: Sharique, it's not just the size. I doubt Mono will work on WinCE/Arm, but please prove me wrong.

Comment: astropanic - Despite what you may think of Windows, Visual Studio 2008 is the best environment for fast mobile device development I've seen.  Using anything else is just making things harder for yourself. If you're new to device dev, you should be looking to make things as easy as possible. You're about to meet a whole new world of issues/problems. Don't let tooling be one of them.